# Create a real histogram without symbols

Tags: java

I need a way to make an histogram, other than using symbols. Usually I used the *** symbol to make something that look like an histogram, but for my math assignment, I have to find a way to print an histogram, and I got nothing for googling.

I learned OOP about 4 months ago, and I don't know about any class who can do what I need. I already have my data in a .java, I generated numbers, and saved them in arrays.

Is there any way to generate a "real" histogram in Java ?

EDIT: Sorry if I use wrong terms, I doesn't speak English natively

Comment: you could use a data plotting library? There's a fair number of them out there, and easily googled for.

Comment: Quick search for "java chart library" yields: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384276/simplest-java-chart-library
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193953/java-library-for-charts-jfreechart
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129/charting-library-for-java-and-net

Comment: just simple java won't do any good for the goal you are trying to achieve. you need to learn using different libraries and APIs for more advanced stuff. e.g. opengl/opencl, chart libraries and other graphic libraries. I have used opengl in past in C++ for creating histogram of images it works well for image processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many third party libraries for this. [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is a popular and easy one to use.

But since you said this was an assignment, Ill assume maybe third party libraries are out of the question, so I'll give you a simple standard Java solution/option.

You can paint the histogram onto a panel, using the `Graphics` API. You can read more at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Basically what you can do with your array of numbers is draw a rectangle for each of the numbers. The number will determine the height of the rectangle. A few answers you may want to look at to help with the logic are [How to make a dynamic frequency histogram from user input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22075683/2587435),  [Paint a histogram via fillRect()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22361960/2587435), and also [How do I change the size of a rectangle while painting a histogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20920337/2587435)

[image]